# Find the solution of differential equation $y' = (y-1)^2$, $y(0) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
y' = (y-1)^2,\quad y(0) = 1.
$$
It asks you to find an explicit solution to this problem. I understand if we plug in $y = 1$, we get the slope as $y' = 0$, and thus its a straight line. Therefore the answer would be $y=1$.

However, if we attempt to integrate and solving for $c$, we reach a situation where we get $1/0$. Is there a way to solve this via integrating $dy$ and $dx$, and getting the correct solution? Thanks

Comment: You can get the correct solution, by taking Marivis' general result $y= 1-(x+c)^{-1}$ and then sending $c\to \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{dy}{dx} = (y-1)^2 \implies \dfrac{dy}{(y-1)^2} = dx }_{\text{This is true only when }y \neq 1}$$
Hence, let us first assume that $y \neq 1$. We then get that
$$\dfrac{dy}{(y-1)^2} = dx \implies \dfrac{(y-1)^{-1}}{-1} = x + c \implies (x+c)(1-y) = 1$$
However, we are given that $y(0) = 1$. Hence, what we derived above is not true. This can be checked by plugging in $x=0$ and $y=1$, we get that $c \times 0 = 1$, which is not possible. Hence, our assumption $y \neq 1$ is invalid. Hence, the only possible solution is $y=1$. Plugging in $y=1$, we find that $y=1$ satisfies
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = (y-1)^2$$
Hence, the only solution is $y=1$.

Comment: +1. In fact, $y=1$ is a singular solution, because it cannot be find from the one parameter family for every $c$.